# finding the lim of the following set

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm given:

$$a_0,\ldots,a_k\ge0$$
for the following set:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_kn^k+a_{k-1}n^{k-1}+\cdots+a_1n+a_0}$$

I need to find the limit of the set. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let assume $a_k\ne 0$ so since 
$$n^i=_\infty o(n^k)\quad \forall i<k$$
then
$$\sqrt[n]{a_k n^k+\cdots+a_1n+a_0}\sim_\infty \sqrt[n]{a_k n^k}=a_k^{1/n} n^{k/n}\to 1 $$

Comment: could you please elaborate of the first line? where did a_{0} go for example?

Comment: $ n^i$ is unimportant with respect to $n^k$ on $\infty$ since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^i}{n^k}=0$ so we gelected these terms.

Comment: @Louis $ a_k n^k+\cdots+a_1n+a_0$=$n^k(a_k+a_{k-1}n^{-1}+...+a_0n^{-k})$ and $a_{k-i}n^{-i}\to 0$ for $i=1,..,k$

Comment: @Dimitris thank you! you made it much more clearer.